# How to access inflated views in a linear layout

Tags: java, android, android-inflate

I use layout inflater, to inflate a linear layout with some buttons and some textviews in it. How can i access the widgets in the inflated layout?

*For example*: I have a button and i want to set onclick listener for it. Normally you declare the button with 'findViewById' and then you set the listener. But the inflated buttons aren't present in the activity xml (the linear layout is in a different xml rather than the activity xml) to find their view with 'findViewById'.

My inflater code:

```
 LinearLayout item = (LinearLayout )findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_duel_basic_easy);
            View child_1 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.linear_layout_duel_1, null);
            item.addView(child_1);
```

The layout i want to inlfate :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try child_1.findViewById(R.id.btn_id)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should work. There is nothing special in here.

```
   LinearLayout item = findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_duel_basic_easy);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 10; i++) {
        View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.linear_layout_duel_1, null);
        item.addView(child);
        final int finalI = i;
        child.findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "clicked = " + finalI, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: If i inflate it a second time it produces error: The specified child already has a parent.

Comment: @ManosRasidakis Edited the answer. Check. Accept the answer if works.

Comment: If iwant to inflate the layout 10 times, i have to make child_1,child_2,...child_10?

Comment: @ManosRasidakis updated for number of times. "finalI" is the reference for the position. which sequence of the button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

According to the comment:

> In the activity xml i have a vertical linear layout (created for
>   scroll view) and in the xml that i use to inflate a have a horizontal
>   linear layout where a button and a textview are

Here is how you can achieve it.

```
LinearLayout item = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_duel_basic_easy); // Your vertical linearLayout
View child_1 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.linear_layout_duel_1, null);// Your Horizontal LinearLayout
item.addView(child_1);
```

To access the view inside horizontal LinearLayout:-

```
TextView tv = child_1.findViewById(R.id.textView);
Button btn = child_1.findViewById(R.id.button);
```

Comment: I think that if i do this i will have given an id to the linear_layout instead of the button inside it

Comment: Is `child_1` a button?

Comment: No. it is a linear layout that contains a button

Comment: Okay, then where is button? In your snippet, `item` is LinearLayout and you are adding view `child_1` into LinearLayout.

Comment: In the activity xml i have a **vertical** *linear layout* (created for scroll view) and in the xml that i use to inflate a have a **horizontal** *linear layout* where a button and a textview are. I want to inflate the horizontal insde the vertical and access the new buttons.

Comment: If i inflate it a second time it produces error: The specified child already has a parent

Comment: Because you _can't add same view twice into parent_. To add it again you need to create new View(inflate child_2 and then add it).

Comment: If iwant to inflate the layout 10 times, i have to make child_1,child_2,...child_10?

Comment: Use for loop to inflate views. This is basics.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried overriding `onFinishInflate()`?

Inside you can look up for the inflated button, you can simply iterate all your children to find the view you need.

```
//iterate children
for (int index = 0; index < getChildCount(); index+=1){
            getChildAt(index);
//check if that view is what you need
        }
```

Comment: How do i iterate ?